# My custom fonts are uploaded and included in the list but do not apply

Tags: php, wordpress, fonts, font-face, dashboard

I created a dashboard that provides the option to upload fonts in .woff format which will be used with the Kirki framework. The files are added successfully but I can't figure out where to output the @font-face code from my custom-fonts.php file.

Code in my `custom-fonts.php` file:

```
function mytheme_add_custom_fonts() {

    $font_1      = mytheme_get_option( 'my_custom_font1' );
    $fontfamily1 = mytheme_get_option( 'my_custom_fontfamily1' );

    $output = '';

    if ( $font_1 && $fontfamily1 ) {
        $output .= sprintf( ' @font-face {font-family: "%s";font-display: swap;src: local("%s"), url("%s") format("woff");}',
            esc_attr( $fontfamily1 ), esc_attr( $fontfamily1 ), esc_attr( $font_1 )
        );
    }

    echo $output;
```

Code in `functions.php` file:

```
function mytheme_get_custom_fonts($standard_fonts) {
    $fontfamily1  = mytheme_get_option( 'my_custom_fontfamily1' );

    $list_fonts = array();
    $list_fonts['Canela'] = array(
        'label' => 'Canela',
        'variants' => array( 'regular', '300italic' ),
        'stack' => 'Canela',
    );
    if ( $fontfamily1 ) {
        $list_fonts[ $fontfamily1 ] = $fontfamily1;
    }

    return array_merge_recursive( $list_fonts, $standard_fonts );

}

add_filter( 'kirki/fonts/standard_fonts', 'mytheme_get_custom_fonts', 20 );
```

Note: the "Canela" font is set by default and the @font-face css rule has been included manually in my `style.php` file.

The problem is that the font uploaded ($fontfamily1 name) appears in the customizer but isn't actually applied (I guess it has to do with the `mytheme_add_custom_fonts()` function). How to make this work?

Comment: Your function `mytheme_add_custom_fonts` might indeed be the problem. To start with: you never call it…

Comment: When do you execute it?

Comment: @Klaassiek the css should be applied when selecting the font from the customizer. It works with this code in my functions.php file: 

add_action('wp_head', 'mytheme_custom_fonts');

`function mytheme_custom_fonts() {
    echo '<style>';
    mytheme_add_custom_fonts();
    echo '</style>';
}`

Although I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: What is the output? You should see it in the head of the html page if you do “view source”.

Comment: Maybe `mytheme_get_option( 'my_custom_font1' );` returns `false`. But it is hard to tell since you don’t post anything about it.

Comment: @Klaassiek yes, I can see the output in the head for my custom font uploaded in the dashboard. BUT I wondered if this is the proper way to do it and shouldn't add a different code. Sorry for being such a noob but I'm new to php.

Comment: It looks like a proper way to output. I don’t think `mytheme_add_custom_fonts` is the problematic part.

Comment: Have you tried adding your font as an array with `label` and `stack` keys instead of just giving it (what I presume to be) a string in `mytheme_get_custom_fonts`?